# How to stop buzz and radio interference on a mini amp

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, buzz

I'm a beginner and recently bought my mini amp (borne strike g30) but it keeps picking up radio signals and making a really annoying buzz. When I change rooms sometimes the buzz will either go up or down. When I touch metal parts in my guitar it also gets a little better. I don't know if it's a grounding issue, but I hope not (cause I can't really do anything about technical stuff). Don't really know what to do, anyone got some advice? Thanks!

Comment: Try a better quality guitar lead?

Comment: Are you talking about buzz with the guitar plugged in or buzz without anything being plugged in?

Comment: both! but it gets louder when the guitar is plugged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The things that cause buzz:

- Poor ground or shielding on the guitar
- Poor quality lead
- Poor ground or shielding on your amp
- Dodgy wiring in the house

We have a number of questions on each of these already that should have your answer, but for simplicity try the following:

- use another guitar, if the problem remains it isn't the guitar
- use another lead to rule it out
- try a different amp if those two don't help.

Comment: A process of illumination - throwing light onto the problem...

Comment: Hehe, did the last bit of the answer go missing? "If those two don't help..." ... switch to acoustic? :)

Comment: Thanks Andy - my fault not checking when on mobile